# Get Teams presence in SPFx

Tags: spfx, microsoft-teams, presence-indication

is there please any way in SPFx how to get people's presence from Teams? I know how to get presence from Skype for Bussines but I struggle to find anything about Teams presence.

Thank you

Comment: Available as Beta in graph since just last week: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta